# Thinking Sphinx posix spawn pointing at wrong directory

Tags: homebrew, thinking-sphinx

A rails application server where homebrew is used, is getting the following console messages invoking org.thinking_sphinx.sphinx (redacted)

```
posix_spawn("usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd", ...): no such file or directory
Existed with exit code : 1
Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
```

So this thing is looping every 10 seconds and (?) pointlessly generating these errors.

searchd does exist, and being installed via homebrew lies in

```
usr/local/Cellar/sphinx/[sphinx_version_number]/bin/
```

Idea where the problem gets generated and how to fix?

Comment: What's the output of `which searchd`? And what's in your `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` file?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/searchd  There are a few applications using thinking_sphinx.  One, which I have not set-up, is a 2.3.10 app does NOT have that config file. A couple of 3.2.18 apps have:   configuration_file: /Users/me/appName/shared/config/development.sphinx.conf
  indices_location: /Users/me/appName/shared/sphinx

Comment: You've mentioned `org.thinking_sphinx.sphinx` - I'm not sure what this is, but it's not part of Thinking Sphinx itself, nor Sphinx. Perhaps that's where the incorrect path is?

Comment: had not clued into looking at the sender.  It is com.apple.launchd with pid = 1.  Start-up item.  I found the launchDaemon with that label. and it does point to the application/config/development.sphinx.conf  file.  Is that kosher?

Comment: the daemon is in fact looking first for the aforementioned inexistant directory.  seems the process is unnecessary as it cannot do what it purports to do.  Is there any reason to have sphinx/ts have a daemon?

Comment: Thanks Pat. As usual, quick, concise and to the point. dunno how that daemon got there nor why it is an orphan.  But eliminating it has not impacted search services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As made clear from the comments, it looks like that the file mentioned (`org.thinking_sphinx.sphinx`) was from an old approach to managing Sphinx for a specific Rails app and/or Sphinx installation that perhaps no longer exists?

Sphinx certainly runs as a daemon, and Thinking Sphinx manages this via rake tasks (`ts:start`, `ts:stop`, `ts:rebuild`, etc). Of course, something to start the daemon automatically when the OS boots is also useful, but that's up to whoever's managing the servers. And it's worth noting that the Sphinx daemon runs on a per-app basis, not a per-system basis, which is why stopping this rogue process will not have affected Sphinx searches in other apps.